# Obtain translation vector from three frames and a common 3D point

Tags: c++, opencv, linear-algebra, visual-odometry

I am using OpenCV for visual odometry. I have a video of a road taken from a monocular camera mounted on a moving car. I would like to obtain the translation vectors between frames.

What I have done so far:

- I obtained matches of keypoints between one frame and the next one.
- I then used `recoverPose` and got the Rotation matrices, the
  translation vectors (up to scale) and some three dimensional points
  coordinates.

My issue is that with just two frames I cannot recover the real
translation vector (just the direction). But if I find the same point
in three different frames and triangulate its 3D coordinates with
respect to the first and second reference frame I think I can retrieve
the real translation vector between the camera at `t0` and `t1` as the
**difference** of the coordinates which I find in the two frames.

**Is the above statement correct?**

Of course it would be better to have multiple points and some kind of voting method. I just want to know if the method is feasible or I am missing some fundamental problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is incorrect. You can only recover translation vector up to unknown scale factor from the set of images regardless of technique used. You need another source of real-world information to recover correct scale and get real translation vector. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57215281/8602076) to similar question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Piotr but I still struggle on why. I assume that the triangulated 3d points obtained from 'recoverPose' are expressed wrt the camera coords of the first frame used. If I just have two images it's clear to me that the scale cannot be retrieve (an infinite number of second camera position allow the same triangulation) but I thought that a third clear this up. If it doesn't I struggle find meaning in the coords of the 3d points given by 'recoverPose' since for a given point I have two sets of coords wrt two different reference frames.